# Java Reflection API. Cant instantiate Inner Class if its not public

Tags: java, reflection

Please help me in reflection api. I cant instantiate inner class if it hasnt "public" modifier. 
I have classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
  String str;
    public AbstractClass (String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
  abstract void process(String str);
}
```

and

```
public class Outer {  

  class Inner extends AbstractClass{
    Inner(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    @Override
    void process(String str) {
        //doSmth
    }
  }
}
```

And i have method in another place like this:

```
void fillArray (AbstractClass innerAbstract) {
    try {
        ArrayList<AbstractClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Object outerClazz = Class.forName(innerAbstract.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getName()).newInstance();
            Class<?> innerReal = Class.forName(innerAbstract.getClass().getName());
            Constructor<?> ctor = innerReal.getConstructor(outerClazz.getClass(), String.class);
            AbstractClass resultClass = (AbstractClass) ctor.newInstance(outerClazz, innerReal.getName());
            list.add(resultClass);
            resultClass.process("STR");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |
            NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException |
            InvocationTargetException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Inner class - is a realization of AbstractClass. AbstractClass will have a lot of such realizations in different packages and classes.

The question is. All it works fine, when inner classes have **public** modifier. But it must not be public. When inner classes have public modifier, i can get a list of its constructors with the **innerReal.getConstructors()**.

But when we delete public modifier of Inner - the list of constructors becomes empty. Reflection api lets me to get inner class with its forName() method, but i cant get its instance with the constructor, because it has not any one.

Thanks in advance for any help! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set constructor as accessible

this should work:

```
Constructor<?> ctor = innerReal.getConstructor(outerClazz.getClass(), String.class);
ctor.setAccessible(true); // can throw some sort of Exception
AbstractClass resultClass = (AbstractClass) ctor.newInstance(outerClazz, innerReal.getName());
```

Comment: Oh, yeah! It helped to me! It works fine! Thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 1):

Try `getDeclaredConstructors()`, it can help you.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! Really i tried getDeclared...() methods. It seems i've confused in my attempts =) Thank you very much! =)

Comment: So, in my sandbox from where i copied the simplified example it works fine. But in real project it  fails with message:

Exception occurred in target VM: Class ... can not access a member of class Outer$Inner with modifiers "". The access modifiers are the same such in an example..

Comment: In this case probably the `SecurityManager` in your production environment forbids the access. Try to reproduce in your local environment, and tweak the `SecurityManager` until you got a solution.